# how to sync the android sqlite table to table on remote DB server?

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, synchronization

I like to write a android application, which will require the basic sync of the sqlite database table from android phone to remote db server, it is better to sync between sqlite (on android) to Mysql (DB server), but will accept the option of sqlite to sqlite sync if it is too hard to sync between sqlite and mysql.
  I prefer some kind of web service or tool based, but will accept any idea of how to program it, please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025812/synchronizing-an-sqlite-client-database-with-a-mysql-server-database

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in synching SQLite to an Oracle Database, you may want to look at the latest release of the [Oracle Database Mobile Server](http://bit.ly/fNuSkR) (formally known as Oracle Database Lite). The sync server now supports synchronizing between SQLite or [Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/eKvOPB) client databases and an Oracle Server back-end. The Oracle Database Mobile Server is very scalable and highly configurable. It's got a great Device Management console as well.

Comment: Hi, I am also interested in a similar solution but as the project I am working at is basically Open Source and also we have not much budget for it I would like to have an approximated cost estimation on this solution. Do you have any clue? How much it costs?

Comment: It depends on how many mobile servers you need and the class of server you intend to run it on. You can contact Oracle Sales by calling 1-800-633-0738 or by sending an email to oraclesales_us@oracle.com. You can also find the Oracle price list online, but your best bet is to speak to someone in sales. Sorry -- I'm not in Sales.