# Is there a way to read and write a mysqldatabase with ajax?

Tags: javascript, android, ajax

I'm currently working on my fist app for android phones and I want to sync a local sqlite db with a remote mysql db on a webserver. Due to platform independence I want to omit all other programming languages other than javascript and its framworks.

Im totally new to app programming...
Is it possible to access a remote db only by ajax or some similar js-based technologies?

Do you know good tutorials to that issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025812/synchronizing-an-sqlite-client-database-with-a-mysql-server-database

Comment: @ItayKinnrot Thanks for your crosslink! But im missing the ajax/javascript aspect...i can imagine how sync work...but can i use ajax for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you intend to use Rhino, which is a JavaScript interpreter written in Java, then no. Standard JavaScript interpreters cannot access a database server because they have no client for any of the relationship databases in mainstream use. CouchDB, which is not a RDBMS, is the closest you could get to a database that understands HTTP (which is the real prerequisite with AJAX).

The best way to sync between a local database and a remote one would be to write a web service layer for the remote one that lets your Android app call it. Don't waste your time with JavaScript on Android or iOS. Just go straight to Java or Objective-C for the phone/tablet client.

Comment: Thomson i was expecting such an answer...that sounds odd ;-P When it comes to databases most of the approaches devide themselves along platforms...or is there a common framework which uses iOS and Android the like...including db communications...?

Answer (score 1):

Platform independence?

To edit the MySQL database with ajax you would simply post to a PHP page which inserts the data into the database.

PHP is a server-side language which means that no matter which browser you use, it will always work the same way.

As soon as the user clicks a link, the browser would make a hidden call which would not even be seen by the user which would write to the database. This would work on all platforms. Is this the functionality you want?

Comment: to be honest...i really would look to a solutions which omits php or the like...but i guess you are right...php is the most common language to achive this goal...but i would use python instead...but that is just a matter of flavour...Thanks for your answer

Comment: I just always avoid straying too far from mainstream languages. Any javascript solutions would not be pure javascript and may have surprising bugs which would cause more hassle than it's worth in the long run.