# How to synchronize ios sqllite database with mysql?

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I want to sync sqlite database with MySQL. I am creating offline application. When i click on "Sync" button, my sqlite database sync with MySQL database and download back this database. I try it, but I didn't got any solution. If any one know this think, please help me.

Comment: Paste code which you have tried.

Comment: can you please give me solution?  I didn't do any code but i am only searching in google.

Comment: You can get basic idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025812/synchronizing-an-sqlite-client-database-with-a-mysql-server-database